# searchBarTextDidEndEditing for UISearchBar does not fire in tab until tab is clicked twice swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

On one of the tabs in my UITabBarController, I have this code:

```
@IBAction func goToComps(_ sender: Any)
    {
        cameFromProfileComp = true
        globalUsernameRef = usernameRef
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    }
```

The issue is, when I go to the tab at the selected index, `searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar)` does not run unless you go back to the previous tab and press the button with the IBAction to come back. Then the search bar works as intended. I'm not sure why this is:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if cameFromProfileRec
        {
            searchBar.text = "u/" + globalUsernameRef
            searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar)
            cameFromProfileRec = false
        }
    }
```

I've tried putting this code in ViewDidLoad, but that did nothing.

Comment: Did you try `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @JustMakeStuff yes, still does not work